# Populating a subcategory JList based on a selection from a Primary JList and info in a database (Java, SQL)

Tags: java, sql, database, netbeans

I have a table with employees, showing their ID. That is listed on a JList. Now when I select an employee from the JList I need another JList to be populated, on what domain they are working on.

I have a table, in my database, that shows that: EmpID01 = DomID02 etc.

How can I get all domains listed from a specific employee(selected one)?

UPDATE:

Here is the code I've used to input values from the databse into my vaules in the JList:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result = 
                        idb.fetchRows("Select eid, name, address, phone_number, department from Employee;");


        for(HashMap<String,String> empRow : result) {
            Employee emp = new Employee (
                    (empRow.get("eid")), 
                    empRow.get("name"), 
                    empRow.get("address"), 
                    empRow.get("phone_number"),
                    empRow.get("department")

            );
            limodEmployees.addElement(emp);
        }
```

This code above I used on a metod that is executed with the constructor. And this is the code I have so far in the JList method:

```
   int selection = jEmployeesEmployeeli.getSelectedIndex();

    if(selection >= 0 && selection < limodEmployees.size()) {

    Employee emp = (Employee) limodEmployees.getElementAt(selection);
```

Comment: By executing a SQL query. What do you have problems with? What have you tried?

Comment: I don't really know how do make it work.. I have managed to input the values ID, Name etc. in each and every employee but I don't know how to pick out the ID from the selected employee and use it together for the SQL question I need to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific on how you made your JList. Which constructor/method did you use to populate JList?
You can get your Object if you have used the Object[] to populate by using the getElementAt(int index). Then cast Object to your POJO and retrieve the key or domain_id in your case. Then make a usual sql query with or without joins using this key as a parameter.